# How can I skip display of repeat events on the manage events page?

Tags: civievent, api

I need to skip showing repeat events on the manage events section.How can that be implemented programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some custom code via extension to hide some rows on manage event page. Some quick thoughts are -

- Override `templates/CRM/Event/Page/ManageEvent.tpl` file and hide the rows having `repeating` text on it via js or using some tpl if condition.
- Use hooks to modify the template variable `$rows` which is printed on the page. Some hooks that you can check is [hook_civicrm_buildForm](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/), [hook_civicrm_alterContent](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterContent/), [hook_civicrm_pageRun](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_pageRun/), etc. See the list at https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/list/